# Vuforia Unity AR seeing database 3d object inside unity scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

In vuforia image tracking, we can see the image inside unity editor and thus we are able to position any game object relative to that easily.
Is there anyway that in 3d Object detection too, is it possible to view the 3d object that is going to be tracked inside the editor so that we can position other game objects easily?
We have 3d object database in .odd and .dat file formats. Is there anyway to visualise them inside unity editor?

Comment: I am not familiar with object tracking but I would assume the visualize object is placed at (0, 0, 0), if so, you could then place a mock model there, either a realistic representation or something kinda shaped in the same way.

Comment: @everts thanks again. my problem is my model has multiple parts and i hv to precisely keep all of them at their respective positions where the 3d object to be identified is.